# define a Python list with a number as the name

Tags: python, list

I think that I'm being dumb, but I can't figure out the answer, and I can't find a solution when searching, so apologies in advance, but...

I want to define an empty list in Python, which in know I can do using:

```
list = []
```

But my code has list names that are numbers, e.g.:

```
0030 = []
```

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

So am I not about to use a number as a list name, and if not, how do I work around that please?

Comment: 0030 is an invalid [identifier](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

Comment: In short, you can't have a variable named `0030`. You could perhaps name your variable `var0030`

Comment: Read python naming conventions.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a dict or a list of lists? If you think you need numbered variables, you usually shouldn't be using separate variables at all.

Comment: How is Python supposed to distinguish between the var name `0030` and the literal `0030`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you dynamically creating lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't do that as Python names have to fit a certain pattern (and [starting with a number is not allowed](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)).... but if you have lots of them and wanted to group them, then you could put them in a `dict` and use your name as a key:

```
lists = {}
lists['0030'] = []
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a variable start with a number.  That is just Python's syntax rules.  You could do something like this:

```
l_0030 = []
```

or even:

```
_0030 = []
```

All variables must start with either a letter or an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use `0030` as a variable name. Quite simply, you cannot have a variable called `0030`. You could, for example, call it `l0030` instead (the first character is the lowercase letter 'ell').

Answer (score 1):

A simple explanation from http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch02s03.html:

> Python has some conventions for variable names. You can use any letter, the special characters “_” and every number provided you do not start with it. White spaces and signs with special meanings in Python, as “+” and “-” are not allowed.

You should be naming your variables something meaningful instead, but if you insist on using only numbers, you could use a dictionary:

```
myLists = {}
myLists['0030'] = []
```

Comment: Just be careful if you try using the integer itself as the key instead of the string version. `myLists[30] = []` will work, but `myLists[0030] = []` will give unexpected results. (For that matter are you sure you are using 0030 properly? Try `print 0030+ 1`)